# How to fix the width of a DIV to its parent TD

Tags: javascript, html

Here's what I would like to see on my website. A table with the width of the body, and three columns: 20%, 70%, 10%. As the browser window resizes, so does the table, and so do the columns of the table change their respective width.

The left column (the 20% width one) contains a DIV element, and that contains some text:

```
<body style="width:100%;">
 <table style="width:100%;">
  <tr>
   <td style="width:20%">
    <div style="position:relative;">
     Here goes some text.  This is a lot of text and usually should wrap around inside of the DIV element.
    </div>
    ...
  </tr>
 </table>
</body>
```

This all works just fine, wrapping and all. Now when the user scrolls the page down, the DIV element and its content scrolls up and out of the window.

What I want to do is to "fix" the DIV to the top of the browser before it leaves the visible area. When the user scrolls up again, the DIV should detach from the top of the browser and resume its normal position. The end effect is that the DIV either scrolls around inside of the visible area, or attach to the top of the browser otherwise. This is implemented with a simple Javascript callback that I attached to the `onscroll` event, which changes the position between `fixed` and `relative`. Works fine too.

Now the only thing that I noticed is that the width of the DIV changes! It is equal to the width of the parent TD as long as it scrolls along and as long as the DIV's position is `relative`. The moment the Javascript callback changes the position to `fixed`  the width of the DIV changes and overflows into the neighboring table column.

How can I contain the dimensions of the DIV?

Thanks :)

Comment: <div style="position:relative;width:100%;height:100%"> ???

Comment: @technosaurus: Doesn't work. The moment the Javascript changes the position to `fixed` then the DIV takes on the width of the body! The 100% works, but it seems that the parent element changes from TD to BODY as the position changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @abelito for the hint :)  Turns out that the solution is a little easier than this.  I *do* need to change the width of the DIV element when I change its position, but since the TD has a 20% width, all I have to do is to toggle the width of the DIV between 20% and 100% depending on its position value.  Here is the Javascript which works:

```
var div_is_sticky = false;

window.onscroll = function() {
  var y = window.scrollY;
  if (y >= 250) {
    if (div_is_sticky) {
      // Do nothing.
    }
    else {
      var div = document.getElementById("submenudiv");

      div.style.position = "fixed";
      div.style.width = "20%";

      div_is_sticky = true;
    }
  }
  else if (y < 250) {
    if (div_is_sticky) {
      var div = document.getElementById("submenudiv");

      div.style.position = "relative";
      div.style.width = "100%";

      div_is_sticky = false;
    }
    else {
      // Do nothing.
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're also going to have to take control of the width of the DIV once the position is changed to fixed. If you're using raw javascript, try changing the element.style.width to the parent's element.offsetWidth + 'px'. If you're using jquery, you should use the .width() method. Links:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.offsetWidth

http://api.jquery.com/width/

Don't forget to revert the width back to '100%' if the user scrolls back down.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, the solution is a bit easier, actually. See below :-)